# React Native TCP Socket release on app restart

Tags: react-native, tcpserver

in my app I am using react-native-tcp-socket (https://github.com/Rapsssito/react-native-tcp-socket?tab=readme-ov-file) to start a server on a hard-coded port.

The application starts fine initially, but my problem is that I am unable to release the resources when my app restarts (e.g. on app reload after code change) and I get an error that states that the address is already in use (Exception on socket 0 java.net.BindException: bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use))

Here is part of my code:

```
class TCPServer {

static ipAddress = '0.0.0.0';
static port = <my-port>;

static server = null;

constructor() {
    const serverInstance = TcpSocket.createServer((socket) => {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }).listen({ port: TCPServer.port, host: TCPServer.host });

}

static getInstance() {
    if (TCPServer.server === null) {
        TCPServer.server = new TCPServer();
    }

    return TCPServer.server;
}

static release() {
    if (TCPServer.server) {
        TCPServer.server.close();
    }
}}
```

App.js:

```
    tcpServer = undefined;

    useEffect(() => {            
        console.log("OPENING THE SOCKET!");
        tcpServer = TCPServer.getInstance();
        
        return () => {
            console.log("CLOSING THE SOCKET!");
            TCPServer.release();
        };
    }, [])
```

It appears that the release function is not called as I am not seeing the message "CLOSING THE SOCKET!" in the logs.